# Access object value within bound function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to create an object and append a corresponding DOM element to which I'd like to bind an event that triggers a function.
My question is: is it possible to access the object's initial values within that binded function?

```
function Bloc() {

    this.DOMel;
    this.ID = Math.round( Math.random() * 1000);
    this.startPosX;


    this.init = function() {
        $('#blocs-container').append( '<div class="bloc" data-id="' + this.ID + '"></div>' );

        this.DOMel = $('.bloc[data-id="' + this.ID + '"]');

        this.DOMel.bind('touchstart', function(e) {
            this.startPosX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        });
    }

}
```

Here, for instance, I'd like to access and modify this.startPosX within the function bound to the touchstart event.

Is it possible? If not, how should I work around it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Does The \`this\` Keyword Work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Me thinks you'd be better of storing the `x` coordinate as data on the element, and then use the element to fetch it later, rather than using variables in a higher scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of this:

```
function Bloc() {
   var self = this;

   self.startPosX;

}
```

and then inside your function call it as `self.startPosX`.

> Why the above works?

In the variable `self` you store the instance of the function `Bloc`. When you get in the anonymous function you assign to `this.init` the context changes and `this` points to the instance of this function. Hence you don't have access to the variables that you have stored to the outer context, **using the this**. However, using the above trick, you can you use the `self` to access the context in where `startPosX` exists.

Comment: Thanks! Both your solution and Rax's work, but your explanation was welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You've lost context. Try this:

```
this.DOMel.bind('touchstart', function(e) {
    this.startPosX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it also working once I changed `this.startPosX` to `var startPosX`, and I guess Christos I explained the rationale why it works. Also, I wasn't able to get the `touchstart` event to work until I changed the line below:

```
 this.DOMel.bind('touchstart', function(e) {
```

to

```
 $('.block[data-id="blocks"]').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
```

please note the selector is slightly different, because i created some divs for testing purposes. The [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/ouf6x3xa/10/) works once the mobile emulator is used for `touchstart` event.